# div element not properly positioned

Tags: html

I have a html table column defined like this:

```
<td>        
<form:checkbox cssClass="check" path="somePath" id="somePath" onclick="someFn(this);" />
<form:label path="somePath" for="somePath"><spring:message code="label.someLabel" /></form:label>
<div>11</div>
</td>
```

So there is a checkbox, a label and a div element with text of '11'. 
Now the 11 shows up below the checkbox. But i want it to show to the right of the label.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` is a block element, consider using `span` (or other inline element) or styling div as `display:inline;`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div#Differences_and_default_behavior

Comment: Thanks very much. It seems to me however (I did not include this in original question) that if i put style="display: inline" ;"background-image: someUrl" the image is not shown

Comment: That's a different issue. Here's a fiddle showing that display:inline and background-image works together just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/XT9Yn/. Consider closing this question and opening another about your background image if it's really not showing up.